# Error adding matrices

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, matrix

I have an assignment to code the sum of more than 2 matrices. I coded it for 2 matrices and it worked, but when I write the same code for more than 2 matrices, it doesn't work.

This is the code for 2 :

```
def add_matrices(mat1,mat2):
    new_mat=[]
    m=0
    while m<len(mat1):
        c=[]
        n=0
        while n<len(mat1[0]):
            c.append(mat1[m][n]+mat2[m][n])
            n=n+1
        m=m+1
        new_mat.append(c)
    return new_mat
```

and this is the code for more than 2:

```
def sum_matrices(mat_lst):
    new_mat=[]
    for l in mat_lst:
        m=0
        while m<len(l):
            c=[]
            n=0
            while n<len(l[0]):
                c.append(sum(l[m][n]))
                n=n+1
        m=m+1        
        new_mat.append(c)
    return new_mat
```

when I try it, it writes back:

```
 c.append(sum(l[m][n]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: But `l` is a specific matrix, so `l[m][n]` is an item (a cell of a matrix). You can not sum a single integer: you can not `sum(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `sum` is a function waitng for a list as parameter, not an integer:

```
sum(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

in your line `l[m][n]` --> thats an `int` not a `list` you maybe should do:

```
sum(l[m])
```

that will sum the list in the position m

Be careful, you can't do:

```
sum([[1,2,3], [1,2]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

but you can do:

```
sum([[1,2,3], [1,2]][0])
=> 6
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you write:

```
for l in mat_lst:
```

so that means that `l` is a *specific* matrix you want to sum. Next you produce some coordinates `m` and `n`, and then you write `sum(l[m][n])`. But `l[m][n]` is an element of the matrix. So you have constructed a `sum(..)` over a single value. Now `sum(3)` makes no sense (and is definitely not what you want).

So you will have to do the processing in another way. One way to solve this is to first iterate over coordinate pairs, and then sum over these cells in *all* the matrices. So that would mean we write something like:

```
def sum_matrices(mat_lst):
    new_mat = []
    for m in range(len(mat_lst[0])):
        row = []
        for n in range(len(mat_lst[0][0])):
            row.append(sum(mat[m][n] for mat in mat_list))
        new_mat.append(row)
    return new_mat
```

This code works as follows. We first initialize `new_mat = []`: we construct a new list that will be the result. Next we determine the number of rows of the first matrix with `len(mat_list[0])`. We will then use a `for m in range(..)` to iterate over all the lines. So `m` will start with `0` and then keep incrementing until it hits `len(mat_lst[0])`. So we iterate over all row indices. We do the same to iterate over all column indices `n`.

Then for every row/column index pair, we will calculate `sum(mat[m][n] for mat in mat_list)`. So we calculate the `sum` of `mat[m][n]` for all matrices `mat` in the `mat_list`. That sum is then stored in the row we are building, and eventually that row is added to the `result`.

But we can also use nested list comprehension here:

```
def sum_matrices(mat_lst):
    return [ [ sum(cells) for cells in zip(*rows) ] for rows in zip(*mat_lst)]
```

Comment: thankyou ! Can you please explain what is the meaning of 'mat in mat_list ' in these lines:
        for n in range(len(mat_lst[0][0])):
            row.append(sum(mat[m][n] for mat in mat_list))